# Is there a way to see Gmail All Mail label contents via IMAP if the user has the label's show in IMAP unchecked?

Tags: gmail, imap

I am using IMAP to connect to our Google Apps for Business domain.  I am using XOAUTH2 to connect, and give me domain wide authority.

I am searching through All Mail to find old email that has not had a user label added to it, and is older than 2 weeks, in order to foster the deletion of unneeded email.

I have a python program that does the following:

conn.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')
  search_result, data = conn.uid('search', 'X-GM-RAW', my_search_string)

This is working well, however, I have discovered that if a user has gone into their gmail settings->labels and unchecked the "show in IMAP" box that corresponds to the [Gmail]/All Mail, I can no longer see it.

I get this message:
BIBG3 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/All Mail (now in authenticated state) (Failure)

Is there a way for me to see All Mail, regardless of whether they have the box checked or not?  Or, is there another workaround?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  This is the setting that controls whether the Folder is exposed in IMAP or not.  If they have it unset, it cannot be used.  It would be a security issue if it were otherwise.  People may have it turned off for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Gmail localizes their folder names, and you may want to try to detect the \All flag in their List response rather than assuming it's called All Mail.

Comment: Why would it be a security issue? (A bad idea, yes. But a security issue?)

Comment: When combined with OAUTH, perhaps they are using allowing some Web site, but they have disabled a certain folder and all mail because it has sensitive documents that they don't want others to even have the possibility of accessing